# Get the naturalHeight of an element in angularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want the naturalHeight of an image, I wrote the following directive:

```
angular.module("Discavo").directive("imagecrop", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(angular.element(elem)[0].naturalWidth);
    }
  };
});
```

which prints always 0.

When I run the same with console.log(elem)

I am getting:

```
[img.imagecrop, context: img.imagecrop, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]

0: img.imagecrop
context: img.imagecrop
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

and if I expand it I can see

```
naturalHeight: 600
naturalWidth: 792
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
elem[0].bind("load", function(){
    console.log(elem[0].naturalWidth);  
    //run $apply if necessary
});
```

Comment: I am still getting zero, it is possible that the image is not loaded yet when the function is called?